# jquery and variable

Tags: jquery, html

Im new to this.I have this jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".squares div").click(function () {
           var colorSource = $(this).css("background-color");
           $(".squares div").click(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", colorSource);
                }
           });
      });
 });
```

basically when i click on square it save the color and than I click on another square and it copy the color. the problem is when I click on 3rd square it copy the color from the square I already change its color. what can I do?

Comment: really?? upvoted for stacking click handler on every click?

Comment: Do you understand what `$(".squares div").click(function() {...})` is doing?

Comment: yes it doing it on a div belongs to squares class

Comment: @Nusha Tell us what you want it to do.

Comment: Inside of a click event, you are binding a click event. So, every time you click, another click event is bound on every div inside of .squares. Eventually you may have hundreds of events firing at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to copy the color of the last visited square, then try below,

```
  $(function () {
    var colorSource = '';
    $(".squares div").click(function () {

       if (colorSource== '') {
          colorSource= $(this).css("background-color");
       } else {
          $(this).css("background-color", colorSource);
          colorSource = ''; 
         //Originally ^-- colorSource= $(this).css("background-color");
       }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What is `squareColor`? Oh, typo. fixed.

Comment: can you please explain the if statement?

Comment: @Nusha The if is for the first click on the `.square div` at which the `colorSource = ''`. So basically, you click on first div to copy color and paste that color to next div backing up the modified div.

Comment: @Vega Thank you:) and lets say I want every two clicks ill start over and select a new pair how can I do that

Comment: @Nusha Can you give an example? do you mean two clicks on same div?

Comment: @Vega lets say I choose one square ,save the color, choose another square put there the color. now I want to start over - choose another color and square and choose square

Comment: @Nusha See updated post, basically you would `colorSource = '';` after setting the color.

Answer (score 1):

You just store the color of the first click (if the document.currentColor is null - it's the first time) in the global variable and for the subsequent clicks you just take this color and assign to the squares you click. Is that what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.currentColor = null;
      $(".squares div").click(function () {
       if (document.currentColor == null) {
              document.currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
       } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", document.currentColor);
       }
      });
 });
```